# How to export the data present in await

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am struggling with promises, async/await. Here i want to export the gridfs object to another file but when I import it using require and execute console.log(gridfs) it gives an empty object. Can anyone help how i could export gridfs

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

async ()=> {
    await mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
        const gridfs = require('mongoose-gridfs')({
            collection: 'sharedfiles',
            model: 'SharedFiles',
            mongooseconnection: mongoose.connection
        });
        global.sharedfile = gridfs;
    });
module.exports = sharedfile;
}
```

file where i need gridfs:

```
const sharedfile = require('path to above file');
//under another promise
rslt.data.on('end', ()=>{
    console.log(sharedfile);
}
```

the result i am getting is {} because console.log runs before the script loads can anyone suggest how to fix it. (I am new with promises and async/await).

Comment: Does `mongoose.connection.on` *really* returns a Promise *and* accept a callback?

Comment: mongoose.connection.on returns an object and accepts a callback @Cer

Comment: Is that object a Promise?

Comment: I am not sure but i think it is because it can be returned by async function @Cert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

First, you never actually call your anonymous async function.

Second, your export is in the scope of that function so it never gets set. Therefore your require returns the empty contents '{}' of module.export.

Try something like this.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = async ()=> {
    await mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
        const gridfs = require('mongoose-gridfs')({
            collection: 'sharedfiles',
            model: 'SharedFiles',
            mongooseconnection: mongoose.connection
        });
     global.sharedfile = gridfs;
     return gridfs;
    });
}
```

Then, your export provide the async function (a Promise) to the requiring code. You invoke it with `()` and use `.next` to handle its returned result.

```
require('path to above file') ()
   .next( 
      function (gridfs) {
        console.log (gridfs)
      } )
   .catch (...)
```

Or you can require it and then invoke it later.

```
const getGridFs = require('path to above file')
...
getGridFs ( )
  .next (gridfs => {console.log(gridfs)})
  .catch (error => {console.error(error)})
```

Be patient: you'll figure it out.

Comment: It is saying getGridFs().next is not a function. So, i tried 
getGridFs().then((rslt)=> console.log(rslt))
but getting a undefined value which is not in the case if i console gridfs in the async function itself.